# On integer multiplication, overflow, and information loss

Tags: java, overflow, hashcode, multiplication

I'm reading through [Chapter 3](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) of Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java*.  In *Item 8: Always override hashCode when you override equals*, the author uses the following combining step in his hashing function:

```
result = 37 * result + c;
```

He then explains why 37 was chosen (emphasis added):

> The multiplier 37 was chosen because it is an odd prime. **If it was even and
>   the multiplication overflowed, information would be lost because multiplication
>   by two is equivalent to shifting.** The advantages of using a prime number are less
>   clear, but it is traditional to use primes for this purpose.

My question is why does it matter that the combining factor (37) is **odd**?  Wouldn't multiplication overflow result in a loss of information regardless of whether the factor was odd or even?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider what happens when a positive value is repeatedly multiplied by two in a base-2 representation -- all the set bits eventually march off the end, leaving you with zero.

An even multiplier would result in hash codes with less diversity.

Odd numbers, on the other hand, may result in overflow, but without loss of diversity.

Comment: Ah, so it's not just a little bit of information loss that you can get from overflow that we're worried about, it's *complete* loss of information that you can get from zeroing out the result?

Comment: @BilltheLizard: actually, it's data from multiple properties emulating each other.  Assuming three properties a, b, and c using the above algorithm `result = 2 * (2 * a + b) + c`, you can see there will be duplication in many perhaps common sets of `a,b,c`.  If you use an odd prime as the constant, the possibility of having a set with the same hash values becomes much less.

Comment: The problem manifests even before you've zeroed out the result completely. Consider multiplying an 8-bit hash by a multiplier of two just once -- it started with 256 possible values, and ends with 128 possible values.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of a hashCode is to have random bits based on the input (especially the lower bits as these are often used more)

When you multiple by 2 the lowest bit can only be 0, which lacks randomness. If you multiple by an odd number the lowest bit can be odd or even.

---

A similar question is what do you get here

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(factorial(66));
}

public static long factorial(int n) {
    long product = 1;
    for (; n > 1; n--)
        product *= n;
    return product;
}
```

prints

```
0
```

Every second number is an even and every forth a multiple of 4 etc.

Comment: Cute, you can show by hand that it overflows to 0.  So no factorials as hash functions... not that I would ever have done that.

Comment: Part of the trick is working out why 66 is the first factorial to be 0. And not 128 for example which has 64 even factors.

Answer (score 2):

The solution lies in Number Theory and the [Lowest common denominator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_denominator) of your multiplier and your modulo number.

An example may help. Lets say instead of 32bit you only got 2 bit to represent a number. So you got 4 numbers(classes). 0, 1, 2 and 3

An overflow in the CPU is the same as a modulo operation

```
Class - x2 - mod 4 - x2 - mod 4

0       0      0     0     0

1       2      2     4     0

2       4      0     0     0

3       6      2     4     0
```

After 2 operations you only got 1 possible number(class) left. So you have 'lost' information.

```
Class - x3 - mod 4 - x3 - mod 4 ...

0       0      0     0     0

1       3      3     9     1

2       6      2     6     2

3       9      1     3     3
```

This can go on forever and you still have all 4 classes. So you dont lose information.

The key is, that the LCD of your muliplier and your modulo class is 1. That holds true for all odd numbers because your modulo number is currently always a power of 2. They dont have to be primes and they dont have to be 37 specifically. But information loss is just one criteria why 37 is picked other criterias are distribution of values etc.

Answer (score 0):

Non-math simple version of why...

Prime numbers are used for hashing to keep diversity.

Perhaps diversity is more important because of Set and Map implementations. These implementations use last bits of object hash numbers to index internal arrays of entries.

For example, in a HashMap with internal table (array) for entries with size 8 it will use last 3 bits of hash numbers to adress table entry.

```
    static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
        return h & (length-1);
    }
```

In fact it's not but if Integer object would have

```
    hash = 4 * number;
```

most of table elements will be empty but some will contain too many entries. This would lead to extra iterations and comparison operations while searching for particular entry.

I guess the main concern of Joshua Bloch was to distribute hash integers as even as possible to optimize performance of collections by distributing objects evenly in Maps and Sets. Prime numbers intuitively are seems to be a good factor of distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Prime numbers aren't strictly necessary to ensure diversity; what's necessary is that the factor be relatively prime to the modulus.

Since the modulus for binary arithmetic is always a power of two, any odd number is relatively prime, and would suffice.  If you were to take a modulus other than by overflow, though, a prime number would continue to ensure diversity (assuming you didn't choose the same prime...).